# Make round edged triangle dialog box

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

we are developing an application in that application we are showing text in div like chat box direction but with a little curve like below screenshot.

Requirement screenshot(Marked in purple)

[Required design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V9WP.png)

I have managed to create a dialog box with straight edge, shown below,

```
.big{
    width: 300px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #000000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
  
  .big::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    visibility: visible;
    top: 0px;
    right: -50px;
    border: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 30px solid #000;
    clear: both;
  }
```

```

so how can i make that curve in the current design?

[Current design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeMmi.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this

```css
.big {
  --bg-color: steelblue;

  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3));
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

.big::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  height: 50%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  background-image: radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right, transparent 100%, var(--bg-color) calc(100% + 1px));
}
```

```html
<div class="big"></div>
```

It has the similar concept but using a [`radial-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient) instead of `border` to draw the curved shape.